# Display the files from sub-folders without the path in front of the file name

Tags: windows, command-line

Basically, I want to list all the SQL files from a folder called *Scripts*. I am doing this in the following way:

```
dir /s /b "D:\Scripts\*.sql"
```

(I am specifying the full path as I want this to work from wherever I write this command)

This is showing me the list of files somewhat like:

```
D:\Scripts\subfolder1\foo.sql
D:\Scripts\subfolder1\bar.sql
D:\Scripts\subfolder2\baz.sql
```

I would like to print just:

```
foo.sql
bar.sql
baz.sql
```

Is this possible from a single command? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /r D:\Scripts %a in (*.sql) do @echo %~nxa
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /s /b "D:\Scripts\*.sql"') do echo %~nxa
```